# C# InsertCommand Queries

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, datagridview

I have an access database connected to my project and want to save back edits. The edits only seem to save when existing values are being modified. When I insert a row or delete a row using my binding navigator, It does not update my database. I have tried many queries:

```
        try
        {
            query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", Text);
            adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            adapter.DeleteCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.Update(Account);
            Console.WriteLine("Saved");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException + ":" + ex.Message);
        }
```

In a DataGridView.RowAdded event I added the following code:

```
        try
        {
            string AccNum = accountGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string lName = accountGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string fName = accountGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string balance = accountGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO " + Text + " VALUES ("
                + AccNum + ", " + lName + ", " + fName + ", " + balance + ")", conn);
            adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            adapter.DeleteCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            adapter.Update(Account);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ":" + ex.InnerException);
        }
```

In my RowAdded Event, it gives me an error and in my regular save event, everything works just fine besides the Insert and Delete Commands. Does anyone know the queries I can use to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing my RowsAdded event and all the InsertCommands and DeleteCommands. I think the problem was I was overriding the default InsertCommands and DeleteCommands with bad SqlCode.